# How do you specify line-height in your CSS? One global declaration or specific to each element?

Tags: css

I realize this may be a vague question, but I'm not really sure what's the best approach to line height when authoring a website. Do you create one global declaration for the entire site and then declare individual line-heights for each individual element? What are some best practices here?

Comment: set a default line-height in the body tag and then specify line-height on specific elements if they are different from the body.

Answer (score 8):

Best thing to do is to set it globally on body without units. (1.5 instead of 1.5em)

this way the line height will be 1.5 times the element font size, which results in a relative line-height contributing to your vertical baseline/ vertical rythm.

If the font size is increased by zooming, the line height adjusts itself to the new font size

Comment: Damn, I did not know that. It's sweet.

Answer (score 0):

It just depends how many varieties of line-height you are going to have on your page, if most are going to be the same, follow Lowkase's advise and set the default on the `body` tag and then set the variations on other tags. Or you could have three classes, say `.lhs` (line height small), `.lhm` and `.lhl` and put these classes on your elements to specify the line-height. This way you can minimize the number of lines of code you use up specifying line-height.

```
.lhs {
    line-height: 10px;
}
.lhm {
    line-height: 30px;
}
.lhl {
    line-height: 50px;
}
```